# IoT Edge custom module not reported by device

Tags: azure, docker, iot

I'm using Microsoft Azure to set an IoT network to connect a laptop with Linux as the device to the IoT Hub run with Windows, and while the device connects without problems I can't make the custom module built on Docker and coded in Python run. This is how the device details look like:

[image: Device details]

When following the steps on Microsoft's [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux) everything works like a charm with the temperature sensor example, which makes me guess the issue comes from my custom image URI pushed to Docker. In such field I've copied the address in the shape of `docker pull dockerhubname/container:module`, which I'm not entirely certain of.

Any clue on what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hav you found a solution ? I have the same issue

Comment: Not really, I'm still stuck on this point...

Comment: see my post, I got the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250990/iot-edge-device-cant-download-my-module-from-azure-container-registry-but-it/53259342

Comment: Thanks for your heads up Yassir! However, you're using Azure Container registry and the container address is a "proper" address, which I'm not sure how to get from docker... any idea about that? I don't think 'docker pull dockerhubname/container:module' is the proper one

Comment: You can use dockerhub too if you make your repository public. However, I didn't need to use docker pull at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

try to add your module in the deployment.template.json

```html
"JavaModule": {
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "startupOrder":1,
            "settings": {
              "image": "<ContainerRegistry>/javamodule:0.0.1",
              "createOptions": {}
            }
```

0.0.1 is the tag associated to your repo. so replace it with your module tag