# [Azure][ACR] failure of IoT edge modules deployment to the raspi device

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry

I made the docker image normally and then deploy those module images to ACR successfully. But IoT edge device can't get those image from Azure cloud. when I get the error logs from raspberry device as below.

---

```
raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:28Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_http] accepted new connection (unknown)
Jan 29 17:18:28 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:28Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_docker::runtime] Listing modules...
Jan 29 17:18:28 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:28Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_docker::runtime] Successfully listed modules
Jan 29 17:18:28 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:28Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_http::client] Success generating token for request PUT /devices/raspi-evan1/modules/camera-capture
Jan 29 17:18:28 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:28Z [INFO] - [mgmt] - - - [2019-01-29 08:18:28.411968403 UTC] "PUT /identities/image-classifier-service?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 114 "-" "-" pid(14045)
Jan 29 17:18:28 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:28Z [INFO] - [mgmt] - - - [2019-01-29 08:18:28.430105961 UTC] "PUT /identities/camera-capture?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 104 "-" "-" pid(14045)
Jan 29 17:18:29 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:29Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_http] accepted new connection (unknown)
Jan 29 17:18:29 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:29Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_docker::runtime] Listing modules...
Jan 29 17:18:29 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:29Z [DBUG] - [edgelet_docker::runtime] Successfully listed modules
Jan 29 17:18:29 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:29Z [INFO] - Pulling image evankimcontainer1.azurecr.io/imageclassifierservice:0.2.4-arm32v7...
Jan 29 17:18:30 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:30Z [WARN] - Could not pull image evankimcontainer1.azurecr.io/imageclassifierservice:0.2.4-arm32v7
Jan 29 17:18:30 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:30Z [WARN] -         caused by: Get https://evankimcontainer1.azurecr.io/v2/imageclassifierservice/manifests/0.2.4-arm32v7: unauthorized: authentication required
Jan 29 17:18:30 raspberrypi iotedged[13089]: 2019-01-29T08:18:30Z [INFO] - [mgmt] - - - [2019-01-29 08:18:30.435005975 UTC] "POST /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 307 "-" "-" pid(14045)
```

---

I've already followed below guide and FAQ, but result is same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication

[IoT Edge : device can't download my module from Azure Container Registry but it can from dockerhub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250990/iot-edge-device-cant-download-my-module-from-azure-container-registry-but-it)

Could you help to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have done this correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53258408/1537195
It sounds a lot like your Edge device does not have the credentials to your private ACR

Comment: Also leverage the Troubleshooting doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot

Comment: Hi! @silent 
Are you sure you have done this correctly? > I couldn't see the 'Set Modules' in the ACR service. But I've done to execute command for login docker with ACR ID,PW as below. <br/>
`docker login -u <ACR username> -p <ACR password> <ACR login server>`

Comment: not in the ACR, the set modules is in the IoT Hub -> IoT Edge screen. It is where you defined which modules to run on your Edge device.

Comment: I've done to `set Modules` as your desc. And then I executed `Build IoT Edge solution` menu for regeneration of `config/deployment.json` file at visual studio code after `.env` files editing. Also I did `create Deployment to Single Device`. 
But result is same on my side. I saw the logs as below after reboot.

Comment: ...Jan 30 17:26:54 raspberrypi iotedged[25669]: 2019-01-30T08:26:54Z [WARN] - Could not pull image evankimcontainer1.azurecr.io/imageclassifierservice:0.2.4-arm32v7
Jan 30 17:26:54 raspberrypi iotedged[25669]: 2019-01-30T08:26:54Z [WARN] -         caused by: manifest for evankimcontainer1.azurecr.io/imageclassifierservice:0.2.4-arm32v7 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
...